ubuntu22.04 "ctrl + `" doesn't work in vscode (it is occupied by a certain function of the ubuntu system）
system: ubuntu 22.04
problem: When I press the Ctrl+` key, a window will pop up.The content of the window is as follows："Software Updates Available to Download. Please download waiting software updates"
the function of "ctrl + `" in vscode is open a terminal. it doesn't work now.
I checked the system's shortcut keys and found that ctrl+` is not being used.
how to fix this problem?

the "ctrl + `" key even don't work on the keyboard test website.

but ctrl + ` key works on wayland and don't work on xorg.
